# How do I filter out git-log commits that are topologically irrelevant?

Tags: git

I'm trying to visualize the relationship between branches in a git repository. There's a lot of commits in them, so `git log --oneline --graph` and `git show-branch` have a lot of noise.

I'd like the graph to show only:

- the refs given on the command line
- commits in their history with more than one parent, and those parents
- commits in their history with more than one child, and those children

Can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get close with `--simplify-by-decoration`, that will additionally list commits that have a tag on them.  To cut unwanted chatter you can use one of my favorite tricks,

```
git clone -ns --no-tags . `mktemp -d`
git -C $_ log --graph --decorate --oneline --all --simplify-by-decoration
```

That clone will be tiny, for the linux repo it's 36KB.

This doesn't list the direct parents of every merge, it picks different parts of the ancestry to show the structure as compactly as possible without losing any of it, but it may be close enough to serve.

You can't find children of a commit starting from that commit, you have to walk back from all the tips you care about, so if a commit's not in any branch this won't find it.But then, if a commit's not in any history, it's not really going anywhere anyway, so...

Comment: This isn't quite what I asked for, but it's close enough to what I wanted that it'll do.

Comment: I would very much like to see which commits my branches are forked from. These seem like obvious points I should be able to see, is there really no tool that can show them to me in a nice graph view?

Comment: @BenFarmer there are quite a few takes on this here, [here's mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58416014/how-can-i-find-the-first-commit-of-a-branch-with-jgit/58595799#58595799).

Comment: @jthill Ok that makes sense, but I'm not sure why it means a tool can't show me the parent commits of the first new commits on my branches? Like in your diagram there I want to see A and B, and I guess the branch tips, but squash the rest as "topologically irrelevant".

Comment: @BenFarmer because, as that link points out, commits aren't "on" branches. The entire link is explaining that point. For the actual work, only ancestry matters, not how someone might have referred to it long ago. And so forth. Read that link again. Branch names *do not matter*. Whatever you've got them confused with, GIt's got better ways of doing, but you've got your grip so tightly on this old, crappy workaround you can't see past it to what you're actually trying to do with it. Why, *exactly*, do you care?

Comment: I don't care what branch a commit is "on", I want to know the points at which branches diverge from each other. This is for investigating issues in the git history, I want to know the point in the history I need to look at to see whether or not some problem exists, and I don't want to scroll past thousands of commits to find these divergence points nor ask branches one by one what those points are. I just want to see them on a graph, because they are the obvious node points of the graph.

Comment: Like I don't care where certain commits originated. I just want to know the current topological state of all my branches relative to each other. If some of them get rebased onto master or some such then fine, the divergence point moves up. I still want to know whatever it currently is.