# How can I find the first commit of a branch with JGit?

Tags: java, git, version-control, branch, jgit

I want to find the first commit for a specific branch, using Eclipse's JGit library. For example if I have

```
master -- a -- c -- d -- e
          \
  feature  b -- f -- g -- h
            \
    another  j -- k -- l
```

```java
// findBranchRoot() is the magic method we want to create
repository.resolve("feature").findBranchRoot().getId(); // this would return b
repository.resolve("another").findBranchRoot().getId(); // this would return j
```

Does anyone know how to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you're going to have is that—and bear with me, here—commits aren't "on" branches.  To see this, consider the graph you drew.  It's ambiguous. Unavoidably so.  You drew

```
A---C---D---E          master
 \
  B---F---G---H        feature
   \
    J---k---L          another
```

and there is simply no way to determine whether `B` was made "on" `feature` or `another` (or, for that matter, which of the three `A` was made "on").

```
A---C---D---E          master
 \
  B---J---K---L        another
   \
    F---G---H          feature
```

shows *exactly* the same history.  It's all in how you choose to interpret it.

If you want to tie a commit to some external administrative record, put a marker in the commit message, that'll do it, but in Git itself (and to the actual work) it's the history structure that matters, not how bits of it are referred to in this repo or that.

If it comes time to publish `feature` or `another`, you're going to need to push commit `B` either way, unless it's already been pushed as part of some other work.  Ancestry matters.  Branch names don't.

Comment: Oh okay this makes total sense. Thank you for taking the time to answer :)

Answer (score 0):

If *first commit* means the most recent/youngest commit of a branch, you can use the `ObjectId` returned by `Repository::resolve` to obtain the `RevCommit` (JGit's representation of a commit object) with a `RevWalk`:

```java
ObjectId commitId = repository.resolve("refs/heads/feature");
try(RevWalk revWalk = new RevWalk(repository)) {
  RevCommit commit = revWalk.parseCommit(commitId);
}
```

I recommend to pass the fully qualified ref to `resolve` (as in the example). Otherwise chances are you get an `AmbiguousObjectException` or the method returns a note or tag of the same short name.

Comment: No I meant the first commit that was commited to the branch. The origin/root of this branch.

Comment: Ah, I misread the 'commit graph' - will update my answer accordingly.