# Get the source branch of a tag on GitHub Actions

Tags: git, github-actions

I am now designing the CICD pipeline and planned to trigger by tag and the source branch name would be needed as input.

The `${{ github.ref_name }}` shows the source branch when it is a commit, but it shows the tag name when it is a tag creation. I know a tag is from a specific commit, and a commit is from a branch. I am wondering if there's any way to retrieve the source branch from tag directly, or commit from a tag then source branch from that commit.

Thanks.

Comment: "I know a tag is from a specific commit, and a commit is from a branch."— no, this is wrong. Whatever led you to believe these things about Git commits needs fixing.

Comment: @jthill what is the correct concept?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58416014/how-can-i-find-the-first-commit-of-a-branch-with-jgit/58595799#58595799

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I use this way to fetch the branch name.

```
run: |
  raw=$(git branch -r --contains ${{ github.ref }})
  branch=$(echo ${raw##*/} | tr [:upper:] [:lower:])
  echo "branch=$branch" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
  echo "Branch is $branch."
```

Answer (score 2):

Not with any env variable from GitHub, since the tag is only given and points to a commit, not a branch. You could look at the solutions given here:
[Identifying a tag belongs to which branch in git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11405134/identifying-a-tag-belongs-to-which-branch-in-git)